# Making non pop-up window transparent in mfc

Tags: mfc

Can i make a **non popup window** transparent and also ensure the child windows are not transparent?
Also i have to block click through by transparent window?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you mean transparent and not invisible, have a look at [Alpha Blending](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/frameworks/advancedui/windowingtechniquesandclasses/article.php/c3213/).

Comment: Did you try the sample project? It is a regular window that the transparency is applied on. Maybe I got the non popup window wrong?